# ComponentSpace SAML - Augment AuthnRequest XML before sign & send

Tags: saml-2.0, component-space

I'm evaluating a SAML library from ComponentSpace vs. hand-rolling. I've read the docs from cover-to-cover.

Up to now its proved to save more time than manually writing requests, but my IDP makes use of `samlp:Extensions` and an additional attribute on the `samlp:Issuer` element.

It'd be convenient if there was a way to access and augment the generated XML document just prior to signing and 'sending'.

Our IDP also uses this lib (apparently) and since they use all these extra XML nodes, I assume there's a way. Just can't see it.

Thanks, Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, this is how to add the extensions:

```
AuthnRequest authnRequest = new AuthnRequest();
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<myCustomField>123</myCustomField>");
authnRequest.Extensions = new Extensions();
authnRequest.Extensions.Data = doc.ChildNodes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll update as I work through it.

ComponentSpace SAML has a low-level API and you'll find an `AuthnRequest` type that can be used to build your request.

That type has an `.Extensions` property that takes an `Extensions` type whose constructor takes an `XmlElement`.

As for the `SPProviderID` element, that can be supplied as an argument to the constructor on the `Issuer` type which can then be set and applied via `AuthnRequest.Issuer` property.

Answer (score 0):

Luke, regarding your comment, "It'd be convenient if there was a way to access and augment the generated XML document just prior to signing and 'sending'.", this is something we will look into.

We recommend using the SAML high-level API wherever possible as it means less code has to be written in the application. Also, we recommend avoiding using extensions wherever possible. However, there are times when you have to do something outside the typical use case and this then requires reverting to the low-level API. We will look at adding the support you suggested to the high-level API. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is all possible within the low-level API. You can build a request and get an XmlElement. As far extensions go, the IDP we're using (used within our industry) makes much use of extensions.

Comment: In the CS documentation (that I have anyway), use of the low-level API to build a request isn't shown. Our IDP was good enough to share a demo using your lib, which was excellent.